# What anime does this guitar-playing redhead girl come from?

Tags: missing-itsuka-kitto

[image]

I have numerous pics of this character and she seems to be a performer. I can't find any information on it. I have tried Google's reverse image search and had no luck.

What anime/visual novel/etc. does this come from?

[image: HELP]

Comment: If you have other pictures of the same character, it might help to include them. I don't recognize her (though by the art style it's most likely a VN) and reverse image search isn't giving anything for your image.

Comment: Consider adding anything else you can think of from here: http://meta.anime.stackexchange.com/a/892/2044. In this case, at the very least, when and where did you get these images?

Comment: Both images here have a 4:3 aspect ratio and the art style pretty clearly suggests VN images, so it's quite likely that she's from a VN. However, iqdb, google reverse image search, and saucenao don't find anything, and tineye only finds one result which is a dead link. I looked through the character databases at vndb and acdb and also didn't find anything either. At this point I've exhausted everything I can think of, though I'll keep trying. I'm genuinely curious where she's from because I haven't seen a situation like this before with VN artwork. Hopefully someone can identify her.

Comment: I believe that I have read this character in series where the Main character is forced into a band that plays illegal concerts.  Also the Main character (guy) has really ugly guitar that suppose to be rare.

Answer (score 11):

It's from an old VN called [**Missing ~Itsuka Kitto~**](https://vndb.org/v18035) (Missing ～いつかきっと～). VNDB says it's published in 1998.

Take a look at the girls' uniform. The red-haired also wears a choker and has some kind of antenna (ahoge) at the side of her head.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

[Handoko.Chen's answer](https://anime.stackexchange.com/a/24310) seems to be correct; the images are from the 1998 VN *Missing ～いつかきっと～*. Coverage of this VN is very sparse on the internet, but I've managed to find a bit more information about the character. She's clearly in [the opening on Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VYapcBtvUKM), which shows the same girls but doesn't have any names. Here's another image:

[image]

Her name is 光星 美姫, which is apparently supposed to be read *Mitsuhoshi Miki* according to [this slightly NSFW page](https://web.archive.org/web/20090505183654/http://www.interq.or.jp/world/hazekiti/h-game/missing/missing.html) (which I also took the image above from) and a couple others. Some biographical details (spliced from several sources and translated to English):

> Takatori Yayoi's (鷹取 弥生) roommate. She's in a band and has a rough look. However, in fact she's the daughter of a good family and has excellent grades and is also skilled at housework, being the best cook among all 9 girls. You shouldn't judge people by their appearances. After graduation, you get married in spite of her parents' opposition.
>
> - Age: 17
> - Height: 160 cm
> - 3 sizes: 84-58-86
> - Blood type: A
> - Birthday: September 23rd

Besides the images apparently matching the description and the linked fansite above, the other way I'm relatively sure she's the right character is that of the 9 characters, she's the only one described as having red hair in the bio (the other character with reddish-brown hair in the image is Takatori Yayoi who is described in her bio as having "chestnut/maroon" colored hair).

Comment: I might be wrong, but 光星 = Kousei in jisho.org.

Comment: As a regular word, it would be Kousei, but as a name, Mitsuhoshi seems more likely (though Kousei is also a possibility).

Comment: @Handoko.Chen Kousei is the more common reading of 光星, and is also a possible name. I originally thought that was the intended reading. However, I found a few sources via google (search for `"みつほしみき" missing`)  which include the reading みつほし and none which use こうせい, so I figured that was the correct one. I've edited my answer to include one which looks relatively credible and which conveniently also has a picture I didn't notice until today.